# In R, introduce on the barplot function differents colors for each bar

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this

```
df
v1 v2 v3
1  4  7
3  1  2
1  6  5
```

When I run the foLlowing code

```
 barplot(df , beside = F ,  hor = T , col= c("darkred" , "darkblue" , "darkgreen"))
```

I get this picture

[image: barplo]

I would like to change the colors of each bar... any colors...

For example, the v1 bar would be, for example, darkred, darkblue but yellow instead of the darkgreen color. I would like to change the v2 bar for other different colors: darkred, black and pink instead of the "darkred", "darkblue", "darkgreen"... For the v3 bar, the same procediment, choose any other colors. I tried to put one matrix in the col parameters, but it doesn't  work.

Some solution for this problem?

Comment: Do the colours depend on anything in the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution in ggplot2:

First, reshape the data.

```
library(reshape2)
m_df <- melt(df)
```

Then create a (similar) plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
#add color (quite random for now)
m_df$col <-  c("darkred" , "darkblue" , "yellow","green","red","orange","pink","blue","black")

p1 <- ggplot(m_df, aes(x=Var2,y=value,fill=col)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack") + 
  scale_fill_identity() + coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
p1
```

[image]